# Como obtener el id desde el modal?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Tengo una tabla que muestra datos de una api y permite el típico *CRUD*.

A la hora de borrar por id, cuando se presiona el botón de borrado se abre un modal para confirmar la acción; desde el modal llamo a la función que elimina los datos seleccionados.

El problema es que desde el modal no borra la fila deseada, borra la ultima añadida en la api, si lo hago directamente, saltándome el modal si que se borra la fila que yo deseo. Como puedo hacer que el modal sepa el id de la fila que deseo eliminar?

```
export const TableGuide = () => {

    const [guideList, setGuideList] = useState<Guide[]>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoadind] = useState(false)
    const [showModalDelete, setShowModalDelete] = useState(false)
    const [showModalEdit, setShowModalEdit] = useState(false)
    const [currentPageGuide, setCurrentPageGuide] = useState(0);
    const [viewMoreGuideDataDisabled, setViewMoreGuideDataDisabled] = useState(false);

    const openModalDelete = () => setShowModalDelete(true);
    const closeModalDelete = () => setShowModalDelete(false);

    const openModalEdit = () => setShowModalEdit(true);
    const closeModalEdit = () => setShowModalEdit(false);

    const [aceptar, setAceptar] = useState(false)

    const fetchGuideList = async () => {
        setIsLoadind(true)
        getGuide().then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            setGuideList(response);
            setIsLoadind(false)
            var filter = {
                page: 0,
              
            };

            fetchGuidePaginated(filter)
        }).catch ( (error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    const fetchGuidePaginated = async (filter) => {

        getGuidePaginated(filter)
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(`response.length: ${response.length}`);
            if (response.length > getItemsPerPage()) {
                response.pop();
                setViewMoreGuideDataDisabled(false);

            } else {                
                setViewMoreGuideDataDisabled(true);
            }

            var list:Guide[] = [];
            if (filter.page == 0) {
                list = response;
            } else {
                list = [...guideList, ...response];
            }
            setGuideList(list);
            console.log(list);
        }).catch((error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    const handleShowMoreData = () => {
        setCurrentPageGuide(currentPageGuide + 1);
        
        var filter = {
            page: currentPageGuide + 1,
           
        };

        fetchGuidePaginated(filter);
    }

    
     
    

    useEffect (() => {
       
        fetchGuideList();  
    }, []);
    return(
        <>
            <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Fecha creación</th>
                <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Autor</th>
                <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Título</th>
                <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Descripción</th>
                <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Fecha publicación</th>
                <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Estado</th>
                <th />
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {isLoading && <Loader />}
            {guideList.map((guide) => (
                <tr key={guide.id}>
                    <td data-label="creationDate" className="lg:w-32 whitespace-nowrap">
                        <small className="text-teal-500 dark:text-slate-400">{guide.creationDate}</small>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="creator" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{guide.creator}</td>
                    <td data-label="title" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{guide.title}</td>
                    <td data-label="description" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{guide.description}</td>
                    <td data-label="publishDate" className="lg:w-40 whitespace-nowrap">
                        <small className="text-teal-500 dark:text-slate-400">{guide.publishDate}</small>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="enabled" className="lg:w-32 text-xs text-sky-500">{guide.enabled}</td>
                    <td className="before:hidden lg:w-1 whitespace-nowrap">
                        <div className="justify-start lg:justify-end whitespace-nowrap" >
                            <BaseButton icon={mdiDownloadCircleOutline} small color="tableIcofcv" className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-teal-600 text-teal-600 hover:text-white border-0"/>
                            <BaseButton icon={mdiLinkVariant} small color="tableIcofcv" className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-teal-600 text-teal-600 hover:text-white border-0"/>
                            <BaseButton onClick={openModalEdit} icon={mdiPencil} small color="tableIcofcv" className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-teal-600 text-teal-600 hover:text-white border-0"/>
                            <BaseButton onClick={openModalDelete} icon={mdiTrashCan} color="tableIcofcvDanger" small className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-red-500 text-red-500 hover:text-white border-0"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ))}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="p-3 lg:px-6 border-t border-gray-100 dark:border-slate-800">

            {viewMoreGuideDataDisabled === false ?
            <div className="flex items-center justify-end mx-3">
            <button className="bg-transparent text-teal-600 text-sm active:bg-teal-700 py-2 outline-none focus:outline-none rounded underline" type="button" onClick={handleShowMoreData}>Ver más</button>
            </div>
            :
            <div></div>
            }
            </div>
            <ModalEditGuide showModalEdit={showModalEdit} closeModalEdit={closeModalEdit } />
           <ModalDeleteGuide showModalDelete={showModalDelete} closeModalDelete={closeModalDelete } /> 

            )
        }

/////modal delete

interface Props {
    showModalDelete: boolean,
    closeModalDelete: () => void ,
    guide: Guide[]
      
}

export const ModalDeleteGuide: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalDelete, closeModalDelete, guide }) => {

 

    const deleteGuide = (id) => {
    
        deleteGuidesById(id).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }


    return(

        <>
        {showModalDelete === true ?
                        
           <>
       
           <div  id="defaultModal" aria-hidden="true" className="fixed top-0 z-40 inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity "></div>

           <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto ">
               <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                   <CardBox className="w-full max-w-lg">
                       {/* Modal header */}
                       <div className="flex justify-between items-start py-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600 mb-4 px-6">
                           <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Borrar ventaja</h3>
                           <button type="button" className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" onClick={closeModalDelete}>
                               <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                   <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                               </svg>
                               <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                           </button>
                       </div>
                       {/* Modal body */}
                       <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
                       
                                   <div>
                                       <p className="text-neutral-600">¿Estas seguro de eliminar esta ventaja? Si es así pulsa sobre el botón Aceptar.</p>
                                   </div>
                                   

                                   <BaseDivider />

                                   <BaseButtons>
                                       <BaseButton onClick={()=>deleteGuide(guide.id)}  color="icofcv" label="Aceptar" />
                                       <BaseButton type="reset" color="icofcv" outline  onClick={closeModalDelete} label="Cancelar" />
                                   </BaseButtons>
                           
                       </div>
                   </CardBox>
               </div>
           </div>
       
       </>
      
     
      :null
    }
   </>
    )
}

////////api
export async function deleteGuidesById(id): Promise<Guide[]>  { 
    console.log('id:',id)
    const filter = {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 500 ,
        "skip": 0,
        "where": {
            "id": id
        },
        "fields": {
            "id": true,
            "creationDate": true,
            "creator": true,
            "title": true,
            "description": true,
            "publishDate": true,
            "documentPath": true,
            "imagePath": true,
            "enabled": true
        }
    };

    const response = await fetch(config.apiBaseUrl+`/guides/${id}?filter=`+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter)), {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: getHeaders()
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
        return data;
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(response.status);
    }
}
```

Comment: No termino de entender por qué tienes una tabla de guías y luego en tu modal vuelves a hacer el fetch de las guías y pintas N cantidad de modales. Según entiendo de tu código, no estás eliminando la guía a la que le diste click, si no... le das click, abres la modal, vuelves a buscar las guías, pintas tantas modales como guías y a la primera que le das click a aceptar, de esa envías el id. En cualquier caso, si todo lo que necesitas es el id, envía el id como prop a tu modal y al clickear aceptar llama to borrado.

Comment: correcto, hago click en la guía que quiero eliminar y se abre el modal para confirmar que quiero eliminar la guía pero no se elimina la guía deseada si no la ultima guía de la base de datos

Comment: Pero por qué vuelves a buscar las guías en tu modal, no estás borrando la clickeaste en la tabla, estás borrando la que clickeaste en la modal, si tu query las devuelve en orden descendente y clickeas la primera, esta claro que va a borrar la última. Agrega una captura de tu modal

Comment: E editado el código, le e quitado el fetch al modal y le e pasad por props las guías, pero no se como acceder al id de las guías.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas conocer la ID del elemento a borrar en el modal. Podrías añadir esa información al estado:

```js
const [showModalDelete, setShowModalDelete] = useState({show:false, id: -1});

// ...

const openModalDelete = id => setShowModalDelete({show:true, id});
const closeModalDelete = () => setShowModalDelete({show:false, id: -1});
```

Tendrías que modificar las llamadas en los botones, quizá haciendo lo mismo para editar:

```js
<BaseButton onClick={() => openModalEdit(guide.id)} icon={mdiPencil} small color="tableIcofcv" className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-teal-600 text-teal-600 hover:text-white border-0"/>
<BaseButton onClick={()=> openModalDelete(guide.id)} icon={mdiTrashCan} color="tableIcofcvDanger" small className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-red-500 text-red-500 hover:text-white border-0"/>
```

Con lo que tu modal podría usar algo como

```js
export const ModalDeleteGuide: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalDelete, closeModalDelete, guide }) => {

   

    const deleteGuide = () => {
    
        deleteGuidesById(showModalDelete.id).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }


    if (showModalDelete.show) {
      return (
        <> 
     
      // ... resto del código ...

                      <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
                        <div>
                          <p className="text-neutral-600">¿Estas seguro de eliminar esta ventaja? Si es así pulsa sobre el botón Aceptar.</p>
                        </div>
                      <BaseDivider />
                      <BaseButtons>
                        <BaseButton onClick={() => deleteGuide(showModalDelete.id)} 
                                    color="icofcv" label="Aceptar" />
                        <BaseButton type="reset" color="icofcv" outline  onClick={closeModalDelete} label="Cancelar" />
                      </BaseButtons>
                           
                    </div>
                  </CardBox>
               </div>
            </div>
         </>);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, funciono a la perfección :)